# boost propertytree

Tags: c++, xml, boost-propertytree

Based on the boost documentation here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/container.html

"There may be multiple children with the same key value in a node. However, these children are not necessarily sequential. The iterator returned by find may refer to any of these, and there are no guarantees about the relative position of the other equally named children."

Sample XML:

```
<library>
   <book><title>Title_1</title></book>
   <book><title>Title_2</title></book>
   <book><title>Title_3</title></book>
</library>
```

Sample boost code:

```
ptree pt;
pt.push_back(ptree::value_type("book", ptree("title")))

// This finds the first book and cannot iterate to the second one:
ptree::const_iterator it = pt.find("book");
```

So knowing that, how would you get all the books and be sure you go them all?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the `equal_range` function:

```
std::pair < ptree::const_assoc_iterator, ptree::const_assoc_iterator> bounds = 
    pt.equal_range("book");

for (ptree::const_assoc_iterator it = bounds.first; it != bounds.second ; ++it)
{
    // process *it
}
```

Comment: ...or lower_bound and upper_bound, but it's better to do it in one shot if you really need both ends of the range.  Good answer.

Comment: Curiously, I was a subject of a programming interview recently in which I was asked to implement `equal_range`... Go figure :)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that inside the equal range can be aslo children with other keys? Therefor I have to use an additional key comparison indside the loop?

Comment: As far as i remember, `equal_range` is applicable for ordenred sets, to remember the start and end of a same key that appears in an ordered set, so you will not find different keys in the range.

Comment: This is true for a "classic" equal_range. But it's stated in the [doc]( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/container.html) that property tree is not ordered by key. 

"It is very important to remember that the property sequence is not ordered by the key. It preserves the order of insertion."

In that case I cannot imagine that elements inside the range will all have the requested key.

Comment: Ok, I did a simple unit test and the range really contains only iterators  to elements with the given key. Can anybody explain how it works? Is the logic implemented in interator's operator++?

Comment: From the boost sources It seems that there is simply just another index by name in the ptree.